# Magento Bundle product quantity identical

Tags: php, magento

Hope the Magento Gurus here can help me.

Here the scenario:

A parent bundle product has 4 sub-products  A1 A2 B1 B2;
A1 and B1 are a bundle within themselves  (must be purchased together, and same qty)
same goes for A2 and B2,
So essentially its a bundle of a bundle (magneto won't allow this by default).

Here are my options as I see them:
1) Override Magento's filter and allow bundling bundles (risky, a lot of logic can go bad)
2) Create a new product type that allows bundling bundles (very hard , requires a lot of the built in logic to be rewritten)
3) Build a template-level force on the qty to match (based on special attribute or such)
4) pre-existing module (can't find)

Does anyone have any ideas/suggestions  on the best way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: weird requirement :) tell us one thing For products A1 B1 the quantity has to be same but can it on only One (1) .i.e. customer can buy only one quantity each item or it can be more??

Comment: It can be more. Otherwise I would disable "user defined qty" and no probs :)